# Cant install LWIP through NPM (ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM)

Tags: npm, gulp, lwip

LWIP could not be installed though NPM.

lwip is being used to create sprites with sprity package

- **Reading from the log, it states that i need to update some constants (see code below).**

  ```
  In file included from ../src/lib/png/png.c:14:
  ../src/lib/png/pngpriv.h:805:4: error: ZLIB_VERNUM != np "-I (include path) error: see the notes in pngpriv.h"
   error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM \
    ^
  1 error generated.
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o] Error 1
  ```
- **I could be wrong about this, here the full log.**

  ```
  MacBook-Pro-2:frontend someuser$ npm install
  npm WARN package.json PIMFC@ No repository field.
  npm WARN package.json PIMFC@ No license field.

  > fsevents@1.1.2 install /somepath/node_modules/fsevents
  > node install

  [fsevents] Success: "/somepath/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

  > lwip@0.0.9 install /somepath/node_modules/lwip
  > node-gyp rebuild

    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/init.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/util.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/buffer_worker.o
  ../src/decoder/buffer_worker.cpp:8:56: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
      _height(0), _channels(0), _trans(false), _metadata("") {
                                                         ^
  1 warning generated.
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/jpeg_decoder.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/png_decoder.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/gif_decoder.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jmemnobs.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jcomapi.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdapimin.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdapistd.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdatadst.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdatasrc.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdcoefct.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdcolor.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jddctmgr.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdhuff.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdinput.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmainct.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmarker.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmaster.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdpostct.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdsample.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jerror.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctflt.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctfst.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctint.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctflt.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctfst.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctint.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jutils.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jmemmgr.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdarith.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmerge.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jaricom.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jquant1.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jquant2.o
    CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o
  In file included from ../src/lib/png/png.c:14:
  ../src/lib/png/pngpriv.h:805:4: error: ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM "-I (include path) error: see the notes in pngpriv.h"
  #  error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM \
     ^
  1 error generated.
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o] Error 1
  gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
  gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.0.0
  gyp ERR! command "/Users/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/bin/node" "/Users/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd /Users/someuser/Projects/some-project/frontend/node_modules/lwip
  gyp ERR! node -v v4.8.3
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
  gyp ERR! not ok

  npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
  npm ERR! argv "/Users/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/bin/node" "/Users/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/bin/npm" "install" "--update-binary"
  npm ERR! node v4.8.3
  npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! lwip@0.0.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.9 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
  ```